# How would I implement a system of locks to model a gender changing bathroom?

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I'm working on a simulation of the unisex bathroom problem, and I'm having trouble with the implementation of the concept. I've seen some sample code solutions to the problem, but they all have been too complex and overly elaborate for me to understand.

Using mutexes, I want to implement a simulation where the main() creates a series of threads in a loop, where each thread calls two functions: enterBathroom() and leaveBathroom(). By using global variables that are locked and unlocked by mutexes to keep track of everything, how would I go about implementing these two functions?

Here is what I have so far as the structure/framework of my code:

```
//Global Variables
int maleCount, femaleCount, totalCount;
pthread_mutex_t bathroomLock;

EnterBathroom(int ID, bool isMale){
    //if(isMale)
        //lock, increment maleCount or totalCount?, unlock
    //else
        //lock, increment femaleCount or totalCount?, unlock
}

LeaveBathroom(int ID, bool isMale){
    //Lock, decrement one of the variables?, unlock
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to use one more mutex lock or variable to keep track of the current gender of the bathroom or not or whether I need another integer to keep track of the total number of occupants in the bathroom. I know that within each function is just a series of "if" statements, but I like an idiot I deleted my previous attempt at implementation when it didn't work without backing it up...

Any help at all would be appreciated, either code or just a push in the right direction. Thanks!

(Just for clarification, the bathroom can be either male or female at any given point, but not both, and an unlimited number of any one gender can use the bathroom at once)

(also, global variables are initialized prior to the calls to enterBathroom() and leaveBathroom)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use general structure instead of keeping more global variables. And also in pthread you can't pass parameters like this

```
int EnterBathroom(int ID, bool isMale);
```

so pthread function should be like

```
void* EnterBathroom(void*);
```

more than one arguments can be passed to a thread by forming it as a structure. same applies to LeaveBathroom(). Refer [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) for more on pthreads.

so your struct may contain

```
/* Global Structure */
typedef struct
{
     int maleCount;
     int femaleCount;
     int totalCount;
}gData;

/* Struct which is passed to thread */
typedef struct
{
   int iUid;
   unsigned char ucIsMale; 
}Input;
```

Sample Code....

```
  void *EnterBathroom(void* arg)
  {
     Input * inp = (Input*)arg;

     /* Lock using Mutex **********/    

     if((inp->ucIsMale != 1) && (gData.maleCount == 0))
          gData.femaleCount++;
     else if((inp->ucIsMale == 1) && (gData.femaleCount == 0))
          gData.maleCount++;
     else
          printf("\n Already occupied by Opposite Sex\n");              
     /* UnLock using Mutex *********/    

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I know that I can't call my enterBathroom and leaveBathroom functions from a pthread the way I have it now, but I have it set up so that these functions are called from within the thread function itself, they are not called when the thread is created, but called within the thread. This eliminates the problem you mentioned doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. In such case, there will be no issue. I gave abstract design only.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the various conditions related to Entering the bathroom. I know the 3 cases are: 
1. bathroom is empty
2. bathroom is male and new person is male
3. bathroom is male and new person is female (I left out the opposite of 2 and 3 because its virtually the same)
but I just can't seem to wrap my head around what variables to increment and how the locks wrap around these variables so that there is mutual exlusion

Comment: I just thought of a better way to phrase my 3 possible states:

1. Bathroom is Empty
2. Bathroom is Not Empty, and New User is same gender as Bathroom
3. Bathroom is Not Empty, and New User is not the same gender as the Bathroom

This rewording actually cleared up some of the logic to me, but I'm still having trouble implementing it.

Comment: give me your exact issue. then only I can help u possibly.